# How can I search an object created array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, search

I've made an array of a class artist
The user is able to enter the details of the artist into the console and it saves to the array
I now want to be able to search for the artist by allowing the user to enter a artist name in the console and if it matches the name of something in the array it will print out found or else not found!

Comment: Hint: use a for loop to search an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to run through the array, and in the loop use an if/else statement, if the word entered matches what the array holds in that spot then display it, else do nothing.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

    if(thingEntered.equals(array[i])){
        Print out
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the foreach in java like this

```
for(AnyObject obj: Arrayref){
        if(input.equals(obj.methods()){
              sout(what you want to show in consol);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findFirst()` on a stream of the items - it's a one-liner:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(myArray)
    .findFirst(a -> a.name().equals(searchName))
    .flatMap(a -> a + " was found")
    .orElse("not found"));
```